# Проброска исключения

Tags: java, исключения

У меня вопрос: зачем нужно выбрасывать (генерировать) исключения? В каких ситуациях? Зачем допустим при выполнении какого-либо условия "ронять" программу, если тема исключения создана как раз для того, чтобы ловить и обрабатывать исключения?

Comment: представь, ты включаешь комп, и на середине загрузки он сам вырубается. и ты понять не можешь в чём проблема. или в тойже ситуации тебе на монитор выводиться выбрасывается (генерируется) исключение - типо немогу загрузиться т.к. нет клавиатуры, винчестер не подключен и тд.

Comment: Выброс исключения != ронять программу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Часто возникает этот вопрос - "почему бы не отреагировать на ошибку сразу как она возникла?" Зачем вообще нужно "бросать" исключение, чтобы потом его где-то "ловить" и обрабатывать?

Ответ на это такой: далеко не всегда часть программы, в которой случилась ошибка, знает, как на нее правильно отреагировать.

Например, программа для чата по сети (типа skype или telegram) может использовать системную функция `send`, которая собственно посылает сообщение по сети. Как работает эта функция нас как ее пользователей не особо интересует. Теперь представьте, что во время посылки сообщения, компьютер-адресат выключился (грубо говоря пропало электричество). Функция `send` определит, что невозможно послать сообщение и вот у нас возникла ошибка.

Теперь встает вопрос, что с этой ошибкой делать. Сама функция не знает, что с ней делать. Эту функцию писали совсем другие люди, они не знают в какой программе ее собираются использовать. Например, функция не может просто показать сообщение об ошибке на экран пользователю, потому, что возможно она используется в программе запущенной на сервере, где и экрана то нету, да и пользователя может не быть, так как это серверная программа, которая запустилась по расписанию, чтобы загрузить в базу данных, скажем, информацию о новых курсах валют из интернета.

Итак, получается. что сама функция `send` знает, что случилась ошибка, но не знает, что с ней делать. А кто же знает? А знает клиент этой функции, т.е. часть программы, которая вызвала функцию `send`. Она то точно знает, что делать. Например, показать пользователю сообщение "Не удалось отослать сообщение" и кнопку "попробовать еще раз", если это программа чата. Или если это была серверная программа, которая загружает курсы валют в базу данных, то она может послать письмо администратору и запланировать повторное выполнение загрузки скажем через час.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы разрабатываете какой-то метод, логика такого метода может предполагать ошибочное или неожиданное состояние к которому может прийти алгоритм метода. В таком случае (если код определил такое состояние) Вы генерируете исключение.

Вы решаете "поправима" ли ситуация. Имеет ли смысл давать знать пользователям Вашего метода о том, что такое условно-неожиданное/ошбочное состояние может произойти. Если да (например пароль не подошел), вы в коде при определенных условиях бросаете чекд-ексепшен и декларируете такую возможность в описании самого метода.

В таком случае, тот, кто будет использовать этот метод сам решит как отреагировать: либо изменить условия, которые привели к этому состоянию и перевызывать метод снова, либо завершить программу (если условия не изменить - у нас только один пароль и нет возмоности запросить где-либо другой) либо дать возможность решить это на более низких уровнях стека вызова.

Если Вы считаете что возникшее состояние "непоправимо", но тем не менее может быь программно определено (например какой-то санити чек на определенном этапе показал проблему и ее характер и причина не могут быть точно определены), Вы генерируете анчекд ексепшен либо еррор.

Технически такие типы ексепшенов могут быть отловлены и обработаны, но стилистически они говорят о том, что восстановить состояние и логику работы программы при такой ошибке маловероятно и лучше дать программе возможность "упасть".