# try catch в продакшене

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, архитектура

Во многих видео курсах, когда используют `try`/`catch` говорят про отлавливание ошибок

Но ни в одном курсе который я смотрел, объяснение дальше вывода ошибки в консоль, либо выброса `throw` не заходит

```
try {
  doManyThings()
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
  throw e
}
```

Когда пишут реальное приложение, а не *pets* проекты, что обычно делают в блоке `catch`?

Comment: То, что вам хочется сделать, если произошло исключение.

Comment: Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1326574/218971 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1155164/218971

Comment: в `catch` обрабатывают ошибку, никаких консолей, можно делать логирование на сервер в некоторых случаях, или отображать диалог "что-то пошло не так" и т.п. все зависит от того какого рода ошибка — если критическая то нужно больше действий по восстановлению нормального состояния.

Answer (score 0):

**Первый пример**: у тебя приложение для вычисления математических выражений. Если в твоей функции возникла какая-нибудь непредвиденная ошибка, выводишь пользователю, что он ошибся в вводе.

**Второй пример**: ты делаешь запрос к какому-нибудь API и в случае ошибки обращаешься к другому API или выводишь, что сервис недоступен в данный момент